# Is this diagram of a compiler inaccurate?

Tags: compiler-construction

I am reading my textbook and I see this diagram for a compiler:

[image]

Is this inaccurate? Where is the assembly code produced? It says the output of a compiler is machine code but I thought the output of a compiler is assembly code?

Comment: Not necessarily. Some compilers produce assembly; some produce object code; some produce interpretable byte-code. Your diagram is accurate enough.

Comment: What does the Semantic Analyzer do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all - compiler is a very vague term (see [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/212617) for the etymology). As mentioned by user207421, there are compilers that produce object code, interpretable byte-code and assembly.

However, there are compilers that also produce other high-level languages i.e. they effectively convert code from one high-level langauge to another (see [transcompilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler)). There are also compilers that convert code from low-level languages (once again, it can be object code, byte-code or assembly) to high-level languages (see [decompilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler)). Then there are compilers which generate code to run on other CPU architectures than the one on which they are running (see [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler)). Furthermore, there are also compilers that produce other compilers (the so called [compiler-compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler)) - these take some form of description of a language and produce a compiler for that language.

This [page](http://www.compilers.net/paedia/compiler/index.htm) is a good place to start if you'd like to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement a compiler.

Your diagram shows an example, there are other cases where the compiler does not match to the diagram you shown.